# Object assign and spread operator mutate React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wonder if I did something wrong because as far as I know: Object.assign and spread operator will create new object, therefore we can avoid mutate the internal state with is a bad practice. But in my project those two don't seem to work.

First, in my constructor, I setup the state as below:

```
this.state = {
  article: {
    title: "",
    alias: "",
    category: "JAVA",
    steps: [
      {
        stepId: 1,
        title: "Dummy title",
        description: "The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog",
        length: 30
      }
    ]
  },
  description: "",
  newStep: {
    title: "",
    length: 0
  }
}
```

Later, I add an addStep() function:

```
addStep() {

  console.log(this.state.article.steps);

  let article = { ...this.state.article };

  article.steps.push({
    stepId: _.last(this.state.article.steps).stepId + 1,
    title: this.state.newStep.title,
    length: this.state.newStep.length,
    description: "",
  });

  console.log(this.state.article.steps);
}
```

And here the result:
[image]

As you can see **this.state.article.steps** has been mutated. The same goes for Object.assign. Finally I decide to use and that solved my problem.

```
let article = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.article));
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.assign{}` and object spread won't deep clone an object.

It will **mutate** `steps`.

It is discussed in the following thread:

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 4):

`let article = { ...this.state.article };` is only making a shallow copy of the object. You can manually make new child keys with something like:

```
let article = {
  ...this.state.article,
  steps: [...this.state.article.steps]
};
```

There are many ways to deal with the problem of trying to clone a deeply nested object. This is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could spread the original state `this.state.article` and overwrite the nested values (like `steps`) with another spread.

```
let article = {
  ...this.state.article,
  steps: [...this.state.article.steps]
};
```